# Quite confused about continuous probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm self studying probabilities and statistics, now facing this problem.

> *Use the random variable to represent the exact number of inches yesterday rained.*

Then the answer showed me a figure about the function describing how it distributes.
[image]

But what confused me was that :

Compared to discrete probability distribution, for one X, its Y should be its probability in this circumstance. However, in the continuous probability distribution(in a particular range, it can distribute infinite numbers), how to measure every X's Y(every X's probability in the situation)?

I'm not a English-native learner, so I'm quite sorry for my yesterday's misunderstanding description.

Comment: Im confused by your question can you clarify a little bit more?

Comment: It is unclear, what you have given. Please give us all the informations you have. Describe your situation more detailed.

Comment: We find a function  $f(x)$, called the *probability density function* of $X$, such that $\Pr(a\lt X\le b)=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$. More informally, the probability above is the area under the curve $y=f(x)$, above the $x$-axis, from $x=a$ to $x=b$.

Comment: @calculus, sorry for my poor narrative. I've edited it.

Comment: @user159813, sorry for my poor narrative. I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to realize that in continuous probability, the probability of a simple event happening is zero. Take your rain example: the probability of it raining exactly 2 inches is essentially zero. This is because there are an infinite number of possible observations (1.9999...., 2.00000...1..., etc.).

As such, for continuous probability, we refer to the probability that an observation falls within a particular range. We can, for instance, measure the probability that the rainfall is between 1.9 and 2.1. We do this by measuring the area under the probability density function that you provided from 1.9 to 2.1 using a simple integral. In this sense, we cannot estimate the probability that the rainfall will be 2 inches, but we are estimating the probability that the rainfall will be *about* 2 inches.

**How to calculate probability**

Suppose $f(x)$ is our probability density function. The probability that it will rain between 1.9 and 2.1 inches is. $$\int_{1.9}^{2.1}f(x)dx$$

Comment: But I don't quite understand how to measure every X's probability in this situation?(Since there're infinite number of possible observations)

Comment: I added in how to calculate probability to the answer. I hope this helped. Calculating the probability of a range of values is very similar in both continuous and discrete sense. You just use and integral instead of a summation.